# provide column data type in DBSMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN oracle 12C

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c, dynamic-sql

I have to copy data from one table to another with below two conditions

1. table names will be known at run time
2. records need to be copied one at a time so that modifications can be done in column values when required

I have created a procedure to to do this through dynamic query. Since the column list is not known already I am not able to declare a rowtype variable. I saw an example of DBMS_SQL where you can define the columns for select clause. Below is the format

```
DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(cursor_var,position,column_var);
```

Problem here is that in all the examples I found the column_var were already declared. However in my case I will get to know the no of columns that will be in cursor sql and their data type at run time. so I need to find a way to pass the data type of "column_var" as part of DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN. Is there a way to do that? Is there a better way?

Below is just a sample code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_test (P_TABLE_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
IS
    V_SQL VARCHAR2(500);
    SRC_CUR INT;
    DEST_CUR INT;

    TYPE COL_DTL_TYPE IS RECORD
    (
        COLUMN_ID INT,
        COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR2(250),
        DATA_TYPE VARCHAR2(250),
        DATA_LENGTH INT
    );

    COL_DTL_REC COL_DTL_TYPE;

    TYPE TBL_COL_LIST_TYPE IS TABLE OF COL_DTL_TYPE;
    TBL_COL_LIST TBL_COL_LIST_TYPE;

    V_CNT INT := 0;
BEGIN
    V_SQL := 'SELECT * FROM ' || P_TABLE_NAME;
    SRC_CUR := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(SRC_CUR,V_SQL,DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    TBL_COL_LIST := TBL_COL_LIST_TYPE();

    FOR COL_DTL_REC IN (
        SELECT COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH 
        FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =P_TABLE_NAME
    )
    LOOP
        V_CNT := V_CNT + 1;
        TBL_COL_LIST.EXTEND;
        TBL_COL_LIST(V_CNT) := COL_DTL_REC;

        -- Here is where I am stuck and not able to give column data type
        DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(SRC_CUR,V_CNT,COL_DTL_REC.COLUMN_NAME COL_DTL_REC.DATA_TYPE , COL_DTL_REC.DATA_LENGTH)
    END LOOP;
END;
```

copying to destination table will come later.

Comment: You need to call `dbms_sql.describe_columns` first to populate a `dbms_sql.desc_tab` array which will contain all the column definitions for a cursor. I'll try to write up a full answer when I have time, but you might look at http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml as an example.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamRobertson , i looked at the example. Its good enough when you are concatenating all the values in a single output string. However what i am trying to achieve is to get the record from cursor output as it will be used to load into target table directly. I will  appreciate if you could suggest something on this. Thanks for giving it your time anyway !

Comment: Do you really need to define a PL/SQL record? That will require a dynamic PL/SQL block, which is starting to get seriously complicated. I have some code to create a table from a ref cursor, but I'm not sure whether that will help you.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - Yes , since i needed to do certain transformations in the data after pulling it from source table and before putting it into target table so i needed the data in a record. I was wondering if i could find a way to declare a  row type record dynamically and get the cursor output in that, but i could not find any so I did it by defining a plsql block dynamically and it worked well.